# Splashpage similar Twitter with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, twitter

I am developing an application for a chain of supermarkets. Are almost come to the end of this app and I miss the splashpage. I'd really like to do the same splashpage of the Twitter app, the one where the icon of the bird increases in size until it disappears, showing the main screen of the application. And is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Native**

I followed [**this**](http://iosdevtips.co/post/88481653818/twitter-ios-app-bird-zoom-animation) tutorial for create the animation

First, let’s add the screenshot on the window:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: self.window!.frame)
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "twitterscreen")
self.window!.addSubview(imageView)
```

**step -2**

Our strategy to use the logo as a window into the main view can be implemented as a mask on CALayer. Every CALayer has a mask property that is also a CALayer and lets you mask the main layer or view. Here’s how Apple describes it:

> The mask layer’s alpha channel determines how much of the main layer’s content and background shows through. Fully or partially opaque pixels allow the underlying content to show through but fully transparent pixels block that content.

```
let keyFrameAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "bounds")
keyFrameAnimation.duration = 1
keyFrameAnimation.timingFunctions = [CAMediaTimingFunction(name:    kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut), CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)]
let initalBounds = NSValue(CGRect: mask!.bounds)
let secondBounds = NSValue(CGRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 90, height: 90))
let finalBounds = NSValue(CGRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1500, height: 1500))
keyFrameAnimation.values = [initalBounds, secondBounds, finalBounds]
keyFrameAnimation.keyTimes = [0, 0.3, 1]
self.mask!.addAnimation(keyFrameAnimation, forKey: "bounds")
```

**Thirdparty apps**

try [**CBZSplashView**](https://github.com/callumboddy/CBZSplashView) or [**SKSplashView**](https://github.com/sachinkesiraju/SKSplashView) or [**MSTwitterSplashScreen**](https://github.com/mateuszszklarek/MSTwitterSplashScreen), for same like in twitter splash animation  you will get

Comment: Thanks so much for your information..I am undecided whether to use external libraries, or use the code that I have indicated to you. Maybe the code that I have indicated is much more simple because it is already written in Swift, while the third-party libraries are written in Object-c, but, above all, used Pod that I really like

Comment: choice is yours , if you use the pod need to crate the bridge header (one thing you need the support of another one), if you implement the native code you are the king you can customize anything on your own.